# How to mock context(ActorContext)?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, mocking, akka

I am using `TestKit` to test the Akka Actors. I have a class Demo which has method getActorRef, which takes input as string and returns an ActorRef.

```
class Demo @Inject()(a: A. b: B, context: ActorContext) {
  def getActorRef(id: String): ActorRef
}
```

I have mocked A,B while creating object of Demo.Now i am facing issue how to mock context.

What i did to mock it ?
val context = mock[ActorContext]

But it didn't work.

Comment: Does it have to be mocked?  why not use the akka testkit to provide an `ActorContext`?  similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945414/how-do-i-supply-an-implicit-value-for-an-akka-stream-materializer-when-sending-a/36985091#36985091

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, or what errors you're encountering. I'm *guessing* you're using the `ActorContext` to get an `ActorRef` inside `getActorRef`. If so, have you tried using Mockito to create a mock `ActorContext`, passing that into `Demo` when you construct it in the test, then stubbing out the `ActorContext` method called by `getActorRef` so that it returns the value you want (i.e., a ref to a test probe, or some such thing)?

I'd expect that to work, assuming that's what you're trying to do.